# How to tell if a website uses JSON or XML and how to pull that data?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, xml, json, github

I cannot for the life of me find any resources for the above. What I'm attempting to do is discover if the website I am looking at uses JSON or XML, and then to pull that data. I understand that is a complicated question, so if anyone has any resources I would appreciate it. What I have now is a UITableViewController and in its initWithStyle: method I include my own method call of "fetch feed." My fetch feed method looks like so:

```
- (void)fetchFeed
{
NSString *requestString = @"http://www.fargoforce.com.prod.sportngin.com/schedule/team_instance/850830?subseason=170237";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

     NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:0
                                                                  error:nil];

     NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"%@", json);
     NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
 }];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

I'm so confused. What is mySQL? What is github? If I'm looking to have a sport's team's schedule represented in a table view but the website doesn't even have JSON or XML but uses images (pictures of a calendar), can I create my own JSON data on xcode and put this on a server using mySQL or github?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

OK, slow down and breathe. Stack Overflow really isn't the place to answer these questions, but I want to get you started so you start looking at resources on your own.

A website may use both JSON and HTML. Both are formats that are you see for transmitting and storing data. One common use of both is to expose data via a web service. A web service is essentially a URL which sends data in response to properly formatted http request. So a URL like www.alltherestaurants.com/restaurants?cuisine=Mexican mingt give you a JSON or XML formatted list of Mexican restaurants.

A website need not have a web service. Websites a rendered in the browser using JavaScript, HTML and css. Basically, your browser sends a special http request to the site, and the site sends back HTML, CSS and JavaScript which is used to display content. You can programmatically request and parse HTML from websites, but this is a good bit trickier than using a web service (and sometimes not totally legal) and is called web scraping.

Building your own website is a whole different business. To do so you need a server, which is a computer that responds to http requests, and a registered domain name, so that requests to a certain URL are routed to your site. There are many hosting services which provide servers and handle the hardware side of things, though its rarely free.

A webserver can just serve HTML and CSS files, but most websites dynamically generate their HTML content. Requests to these sites are routed to programs that process the requests and send back HTML.

Often, websites need to store data. The most popular mode of data storage is the relational database. Mysql is the most popular relational database, mostly because it is free (I actually dislike it quite a lot, but that's a matter of taste). Programs interact with a relational database using SQL, a query language.

So a web application traditional ly has three layers:

Client side user interface in HTML and css and JS
Server side logic in just about any language.
Data storage in a rdb.

There are other ways to do it, and lots of sites have many more layers. But for learning the fundamentals, three tier design is simple and robust.

This is a crazy oversimplified explanation. I skipped a lot of important stuff. You should learn this stuff, but stack overflow is not the best place to learn it.

Choose a programming language. Get a book on basic web development in that language. Read that book. Build a simple site. Then get more books. Wash rinse repeat.

If you don't like books, check out pluralsight or use my, which offer video courses.

Good luck

Comment: I guess what my question boils down to is finding the source page (in JSON or XML) for the html page you look at when you use a website. Do you know how I can find this using Chrome's Developer Tools? For example, I'm trying to find the source page for the table on this page:

http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983

This is a site I work with, but the website has been outsourced so no one really knows anything about it I can talk to.

Comment: @Jay, why do you think that there *is* a "source page (in JSON or XML)"? I think you've got some assumptions that don't hold in general.

Answer (score 2):

The link included in your example goes to the rendered HTML page, not the data source page. It is possible that this page is fully rendered by the server and the data is not exposed to client in XML, JSON or any other format.

On a 'good manners' note, unless sportngin.com provides a public API is it very bad form to create an app using their data. If they wanted their data displayed in a third party app they would make an API available.

From a technical standpoint, if a public API that displays JSON or XML is not available you could still scrape the HTML and build your own but that scraper would break every time they changed the page. This usually isn't worth the effort.

MySQL is a database and Github is a repository management service for code.

Comment: Is there a way I can find the data source page for the HTML page? For example, the link I included or this one: 
http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983

I work in this league and have permission to use this info, but all of our websites are outsourced and done by different companies. I'm hoping to building an iOS app (I know objective-c and xcode, but have no experience with any other programming languages) that uses this data from the link above, but have no way of either (1) finding the data source page for the HTML page; or (2) scraping that data

Comment: (ran out of characters). I have no idea how to scrape data from a page like that. 

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how the site is structured. Some webpages are fully rendered on the server side so there is no way to access the data as a resource. Some, mostly newer pages, make a call to a JSON source and then format and display the HTML from that source on the client side. If you review the sites JavaScript code in something like the chrome developer tools you MIGHT be able to find this source but using it in your app is VERY BAD PRACTICE unless the data source provider gives you permission.

Comment: I would pick up the phone and talk to the company that is doing the website and ask them to provide you an API that serves JSON. Any other way is going to be a nightmare and not sustainable or maintainable.

Comment: The permission part is taken care of. It's everything else that is a mess. Can you point me anywhere to learn more about how to potentially get the source page for HTML pages, either using Chrome or anything else? In the end, this is what my question boils down to. Thanks again.

Comment: I just don't even understand what "an API that serves JSON" means. I'm lost. My experience only goes so far as a book on Objective-C and another Big Nerd Ranch book on iOS development. Anything beyond that and I'm a goner.

Comment: So, here is an example of a good API for weather data: http://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: And here is a URL that you would build in your iOS app and make a call to in order to get data back. http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk This stuff has a learning curve. www.teamtreehouse.com has some good tutorials on how to call an API. That is how I learned. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm on http://www.pointstreak.com/prostats/scoringleaders.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983

using Chrome Developer Tools trying to find a source page. Thanks again.